# Can a Postman Pro share collections to Free Postman users?

Tags: postman

Can a Postman Pro share unlimited request to multiple Free Postman users?

I'm thinking of setting up a Pro account that will act as a central request collection store, then Free Postman users will just clone/read from it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done with the same process as sharing a collection within the team, but the free users will not be able to use the pro features like API design within Postman, generate machine-readable documentation, common schemas, servers to simulate, monitoring API performance, API uptime and custom domains